# What's the point of an ampersand '&' before the 'new' keyword?

Tags: php, oop

Why would you do this?

```
$a = &new <someclass>();
```

For example, the documentation for SimpleTest's SimpleBrowser uses this syntax (http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html).

```
$browser = &new SimpleBrowser();
```

Is there any use to this? Is this a relic of PHP 4?

Edit:

I understand that the ampersand returns by reference, but what is the point of returning a NEW instance of an object by reference?

Comment: yes that's a relic, all object are passed by reference in PHP 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP5, objects are [passed using opaque object handles](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). You can still make a reference to a variable holding such a handle and give it another value; this is what the `&new` construct does in PHP5. It doesn't seem to be particularly useful though – unless you clone it explicitly, there's only ever one copy of a particular object instance, and you can make references to handles to it anytime after instantiation if you want to. So my guess would be the code you found is a holdover from when `&new` was a necessary pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Inerdia -- could you provide an example of "cloning it explicitly"?

Comment: @jib You clone an object explicitly using the [`clone` keyword](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: Ah, so this is in no relation to '&new'? You were simply referring to how many copies of an object instance exist, correct?

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP5 `new` returns references automatically. Using `=&` is thus meaningless in this context (and if I'm not mistaken giving a E_STRICT message).

Pre-PHP5 the use of `=&` was to get a reference to the object. If you initialized the object into a variable and then assigned that to a new variable both of the variables operated on the same object, exactly like it is today in PHP5.

Comment: Thanks @marcus. A followup, before php 5, what would be a use-case of assigning a variable to a NEW object by reference? Something to do with overwriting the variable's old value?

Comment: Here's and old article explaining it: http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/archive/2006/08/object-oriented-php-part-2-relationships/. Look under the title "References"